# Marklogic extract DB status from multiple servers?

Tags: python, database, bash, marklogic, status

I need to create a bash(or python) script which gives me the availability status of multiple databases which are on different servers. I found that I can get the status using this url "http://marklogic:8002/manage/v2/database/$DBNAME/?view=status". But I have for about twenty different DBs. When you open this link it generates an xml with database details. Can you please advise how can I loop all the links and grep only the status row ? Or if you have any other idea please advise

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth looking into the MarkLogic Python API project on Github:

https://github.com/marklogic/python_api

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the dbnames in a file and then use for loop around it.

```
for a in `cat dbname.txt`
do
status = `wget -qO- "http://marklogic:8002/manage/v2/database/${a}/?view=status"`
echo $a, $status
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but when I try to open it in a browser it asks me for a password everytime. How can I add the user and password

Comment: there can be mutiple options here if password can be passed as parameter you should pass it in url. If it does not allow you should try to post it using wget

Comment: Set the password as an environment variable (non-interactive) or ask for it once when the script starts (interactive). I don't know wget, but with cURL you’d use the `--user` and `--digest` options to specify digest auth. The community Python API, mentioned above, handles all of this for you.

Comment: yep, I did it through curl --anyauth --user user:pass "http://marklogic:8002/manage/v2/database/${a}/?view=status

Answer (score 0):

yep, I did it through curl --anyauth --user user:pass "http://marklogic:8002/manage/v2/database/${a}/?view=status